# PDDocument addPage /importPage not working correct

Tags: c#, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 1.8.3 and my need is to take a set of ZPLs and convert them all into one PDF. For the conversion part(ZPL to PDF), we are using labelary and this works correctly. I am basically using PDFBox to "stitch" all these individual PDFs. My source code is very simple as below :

```
    var outputByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var destinationDoc = null;
    var doc = null;

    for each(var img in images.toArray()) {
      log.debug("Working with image : " + img);

      if("ZPL".equalsIgnoreCase(img.getFormat()) || "ZPL203".equalsIgnoreCase(img.getFormat())) {

        try {
          var convertorServiceUrl = "http://labelary ...." + img.getId()+"?labelSize=4x6&density=8dpmm";
          var urlObject = new URL(convertorServiceUrl);    
          var conn = urlObject.openConnection();   
          conn.connect();          

          if(destinationDoc == null ) { 
             var tmpfile = java.io.File.createTempFile(pw +"-"+uniqKey, ".pdf");
             var raf = new org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile(tmpfile, "rw");          
            destinationDoc = PDDocument.load(conn.getInputStream(), raf); 
          }
          else {           
            doc = PDDocument.load(conn.getInputStream());            
            if (doc != null && doc.getNumberOfPages() > 0) {            
                var page = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
                destinationDoc.importPage(page); 
            }  
          }           

        } catch (res) {
          log.error("Error message retrieved is " + exceptionMsg);
          throw new BaseRuntimeException("Unable to convert the PDF for image with id " + img.getId(), res);
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      if(destinationDoc != null) {
          destinationDoc.save(outputByteStream);
          destinationDoc.close();
      }
    } catch (e1) {
      log.error("Error in writing the document to the output stream " + pw + "." , e1);
      throw e1;
    }

    return outputByteStream.toByteArray();
```

Source code runs and generates a PDF but all the pages of the PDF are pointing to the first page. So if my for-loop run 4 times, all 4 pages of the PDF are for first label.

If I use addPage like below

```
    var outputByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var destinationDoc = new PDDocument();
    var doc = null;

    for each(var img in images.toArray()) {
      log.debug("Working with image : " + img);

      if("ZPL".equalsIgnoreCase(img.getFormat()) || "ZPL203".equalsIgnoreCase(img.getFormat())) {

        try {
          var convertorServiceUrl = "http://labelary ...." + img.getId()+"?labelSize=4x6&density=8dpmm";
          var urlObject = new URL(convertorServiceUrl);    
          var conn = urlObject.openConnection();   
          conn.connect();          


            doc = PDDocument.load(conn.getInputStream());            
            if (doc != null && doc.getNumberOfPages() > 0) {            
                var page = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
                destinationDoc.addPage(page); 
            }  


        } catch (res) {
          log.error("Error message retrieved is " + exceptionMsg);
          throw new BaseRuntimeException("Unable to convert the PDF for image with id " + img.getId(), res);
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      if(destinationDoc != null) {
          destinationDoc.save(outputByteStream);
          destinationDoc.close();
      }
    } catch (e1) {
      log.error("Error in writing the document to the output stream " + pw + "." , e1);
      throw e1;
    }

    return outputByteStream.toByteArray();
```

Then the result is a PDF page with all empty pages.

I have already ensured that the content returned from the labelary service is correct and if I simply take the response and save it into a file it works correctly. Even saving the PDDocument one page at a time also produces the PDF correctly.

The problem I have is with the "stitching" of PDFs. It should work as per the documentation but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You appear to use pdfbox from c# (judging by the `for each` loop syntax). Are there no newer versions if pdfbox available for your use? Even the 1.8.x branch of Apache pdfbox maintenance is at 1.8.17 or 1.8.18 (I haven't kept track) with numerous fixes.

Comment: If you just want to merge PDFs, use the command line utilities of PDFBox 2.0.18 with java.

Comment: I am using pdfbox from Rhino (JavaScript) and newer version of pdfbox is not a immediate option as this is a production environment.  Command Line is not a option for me.  I have also tried PDFMergerUtility with mixed success.

```

Comment: Also I was able to get this working with iText very easily. It was so straight forward and I was still using their legacy version .

Comment: You should still test with a current version 1.8.16 / 2.0.18 to see whether this is a PDFBox bug. Because if it works then it is a bug for sure.

Comment: Another thing to do is to simplify your code so that it uses only the PDFs, without the remote loading. I think this is a bug in PDFBox (most likely fixed long ago), but I might be wrong. Also share all the files that are involved.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I was successful in loading the PDF content directly from the database and "stitch" the PDFs into one file using PDFMergerUtility on 1.8.3 branch. Upgrading to latest version of PDFBox is a 2 month waiting period in my case and is not preferred choice at the moment.

Comment: So that's two changes, you loaded from the database and you used PDFMergerUtility, so one doesn't know which of the two helped. Or are you saying that this is your solution and you're now satisfied?

Comment: No, I am not saying that is my solution. My solution is really abondoning PDFBox and moving over to iText.

Comment: I am using PDFMergerUtilitiy and loading data from the db for another flow in the same job in which I have direct PDF content stored in the table. You see parcel carriers can return shipping labels in typically ZPL, PNG/JPG/GIF or PDF. One of the parcel carriers only returns ZPL. So if I have PDF data,I am able to load from db and use PDFMergerUtility to merge and it works.  When the data is  ZPL, I have to convert into PDF first (thru labelary) and simply want to use the data and build a PDF.  Hope this was clear